How to update Visual Studio Code using command line for many Windows computers?
I handle many windows server 2019 computers that has vscode installed. I want to remotly run the update, because users don't do it themselves.
I was looking for a command line i could use to update.
I did it once for visual studio:(in powershell)
Start-process "Path/setup.exe" -ArgumentList "-update --norestart --force --installpath '"C...'"" -wait
I cant seem to find the same thing for vscode.
I cant use winget.
Help appreciated.

Given that you're on windows, if you use winget to manage VS Code installations (install via winget install Microsoft.VisualStudioCode), you can winget upgrade --id Microsoft.VisualStudioCode.
